# Remove specific element from local storage

Tags: javascript, function, loops, local-storage

I have run into a problem, trying to code a web application, where the user can delete his or her own account.
When I run my code it deletes the first item in the User array in local storage, and not the element, that matches with the current user (the user that is logged in).

I hope someone is able to help me.
Best regard

Here is my code:

```
    var removeItem = document.getElementById("deleteBtn").addEventListener("click",deleteAccount);

function deleteAccount() {
   var accounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"));
   var current = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if (accounts[i]._username == current._username){
            accounts.splice(i,1); 
            localStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(accounts));
            
            return localStorage.removeItem('currentUser'); 
             
        }
```

Comment: What does `accounts` variable represents ?

Comment: the accounts variable represent the array of created users from the local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter out the current account off the accounts array.

```
function deleteAccount() {
    var accounts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"));
    var current = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));

    accounts = accounts.filter(account => account._username !== current._username);

    localStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(accounts));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy. I really appreciate your help - it works.